# Insert data to openfire database using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am using an external Mysql database for my openfire server and im trying to insert data into the my "openfire" named database , which its table name is "ofuser" and its fields columns are "username" , "plainpassword","encryptedpassword","name","email","creationdate","modificationdate"

this is my code:

```
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                  //STEP 3: Open a connection
                  System.out.println("Connecting to a selected  
database...");
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, 
PASS);
                  System.out.println("Connected database 
successfully...");

                  //STEP 4: Execute a query
                  System.out.println("Inserting records into the 
table...");
                  stmt = conn.createStatement();

                  String sql = "INSERT INTO ofuser " +
                               "VALUES (100, 'Zara', 'Ali', 18)";
                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                  sql = "INSERT INTO ofuser " +
                               "VALUES (101, 'Mahnaz', 'Fatma', 25)";
                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                  sql = "INSERT INTO ofuser " +
                               "VALUES (102, 'Zaid', 'Khan', 30)";
                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                  sql = "INSERT INTO ofuser " +
                               "VALUES(103, 'Sumit', 'Mittal', 28)";
                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                  System.out.println("Inserted records into the 
table...");

               }catch(SQLException se){
                  //Handle errors for JDBC
                  se.printStackTrace();
               }catch(Exception e){
                  //Handle errors for Class.forName
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }finally{
                  //finally block used to close resources
                  try{
                     if(stmt!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                  }// do nothing
                  try{
                     if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                     se.printStackTrace();
                  }//end finally try
               }//end try
               System.out.println("Goodbye!");
               display("End of DB");

        }
```

and im running it using eclipse. but nothing happenes, where am i wrong guys?

UPDATE:

im recieving this error in console:

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at Server$ClientThread.<init>(Server.java:236)
at Server.start(Server.java:74)
at ServerGUI$ServerRunning.run(ServerGUI.java:132)
```

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: i mean database doesnt get updated, and btw i updated the question, im recieving an error in console

Comment: add mysql driver jar to your class path

Comment: @user3647265 you have not added the mysql.jar so getting the error.I have posted the answer,follow the steps.If you get any problems then feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not included [mysql.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql.jar.zip) in your class path.

Follow the following steps

1. right click on your project
2. got to build path -> configure build path
3. click on libraries tab
4. click add external jar and give the path of mysql.jar

Answer (score 1):

Just Download your respective connector which n your case in jdbc from here http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and add the downloaded jar file to your project's libraries.